# Finding duplicate elements in Excel Column and displaying its cell number

Tags: c#, excel, list, vsto, duplicates

I am working on C# VSTO ([Visual Studio Tools for Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430)) Excel.

I have column "C" which is having around 30 values from C1 to C30. I can take these values in the list.

I want to accomplish 2 tasks:

1. Detect duplicate elements in the whole column.
2. Print cell no. of the both the elements (duplicate). e.g.: If C12 and C28 have same element I need to print the "C12" and "C28".

What can be the fastest way to do this?

Comment: What is 'C# vsto excel'?

Comment: @CodeBlend : http://www.packtpub.com/article/microsoft-office-excel-programming-using-vsto  read this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode, untested: (!!!)

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<string,int>();
string col="C";
for(int row = 1; row<numberOfRows; ++row)
{
     string elemValue = myWorkSheet.Range[col + row].Text.ToString();
     if(myDictionary.ContainsKey(elemValue))
     {
          Console.WriteLine(col + myDictionary[elemValue] + " = " + col + row);
     }
     else
     {
          myDictionary[elemValue]=row;
     }
}
```

Comment: Range(col + row).Text not working throw error like Range not as method

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi: see my edit. But honestly, you should really learn how to fix such errors on your own.

Comment: : I tried both the way but still it's not working that why I put the comment here.

Comment: I would recommend using `Value2` instead of `Text` because `Text` gives you the shortened version if the columns are not expanded.